# Plotting a histogram on punctuation occurrence python

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, histogram, punctuation

I have thousands of sentences in series form (rows) . here's an example:
'After hearing his plea, the judge pardoned him.'

'The weather is quite sunny , though not as the other days.'

'Tom,Bill,Grace and tinkle went fishing,even though it was raining.'

so i want a histogram which displays the count of the number of commas in a sentence --

1. 1comma
2. 1 comma
3. 3 commas.

each bar of the histogram should represent one sentence and its height should determine the number of commas. 
"i'll be doing it for different punctuations as well as some keywords".

i have already managed to get the count. all i need to do is display it.. thanks..

this is what i tried.. a1 contains the count of commas for each sentence. i need to plot the no of commas against each sentence

X = [i for i in range(len(a1))]

plt.bar(X,a1,width=2.5,color="blue")

an error that module object has no attribute "bar" . i imported matplotlib as plt in beginning..

Comment: I guess your second point should be: 2. 2 comma. Moreover, what you want to do is not clear to me. shouldn't the axis of the histogram represent the number of commas, and each sentence be an entry in the histogram? that's not what I understand from your explanation.

Comment: no, the weather sentence has only a single comma that is why 2nd observation has 1 . so the histogram will display 3 bars , 1st and 2nd with magnitude 1 and 3rd one with magnitude 3. this shows the distribution of commas in the sample..

Comment: This isn't a hitogram you want, just a bar plot. Look at `matplotlib.pyplot.bar`.

Comment: yes.. thats what . the sentences along the x axis, and no of commas on y axis . so 1 on xaxis will have the respective magnitude of 1.. and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken (the comments don't seem to mention this). Your problem is that you recieve the error `module object has no attribute "bar"`. I think this is because you are doing

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.bar(..
```

If instead you import as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then `plt` as a function `bar()` which you can use. Some more information on this can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html).

Comment: thanx greg, i got it to work using "import pylab as plt". could you tell me what is the diff between pylab and matplotlib.pyplot ?? (i know the basic diff of pylab that it is somewhat matlab based.

Comment: sorry , its mentioned in the link u sent ..thnx

Comment: i plotted the hist using a1.hist() . how do i interchange the axes for the same??

Comment: It is unclear what `a1` is, if it is a list/array then what you have just written doesn't make sense. I would suggest plotting with `plt.hist(x, y)` have a look at the docs and if you have a new question ask it as a separate question on SO.

Comment: a1 is an array that contains the counts of number of commas in each sentence. for the above eg in my question, a1 = [1,1,3] . so i did a1.hist() and have got the histogram right. only the part that the axis need to be interchanged. y becomes x and x becomes y.